# ReactJs, next JS, express and redux boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, next.js

I'm starting a project which I code with node-express, react, redux and nextjs.

Been searching a lot on the web, saw a lot of exaples, but no even one boilerplate that have all pieces together ready as an infrastructure to start a new project for production.

Already found the following, but they are all rather very simple or extremely overhead for just a boilerplate:

[RAN!](https://github.com/sly777/ran)

[NextSimpleStarter](https://github.com/ooade/NextSimpleStarter)

[Official examples](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would help in reducing the boilerplate for redux significantly:
https://github.com/anish000kumar/redux-box

Answer (score 0):

why not check out this boilerplate :  https://github.com/tomsoderlund/nextjs-express-mongoose-crudify-boilerplate.git

it has

- Next.js (React)
- Redux
- Express REST API
- MongoDB